# opensource TCP server framework

Tags: c, frameworks, tcpserver

Any open source tcp server framework ( preferably event loop model than multithreaded ) in C ?

Found a lot of libraries like boost for c++ but couldn't find anything for C.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Shameless self-promotion](https://github.com/H2CO3/TCPHelper/blob/master/tcpconnect.c)

Answer (score 0):

libevent and libev are both ok.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't C but I have released an open source C# TCP server that includes C#, Java and Objective-C client APIs.  It's called [DotNetOpenServer SDK](http://www.uppersetting.com/DotNetOpenServer).

Comment: Typically, Link only answers are discouraged.  But since it's what the OP asked for, I'll just say welcome to Stack Overflow.